# Third-party components on TeamCity build agents

Tags: teamcity

How does TeamCity work when you have a paid third-party component that needs to be installed on the machine?

I have a little .NET application that uses an Atalasoft component.

Do I need to install that component in the agent?
What if I have more than one agent? Dedicated agent?

Answer (score 0):

better to resolve libraries with [`nuget`](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Atalasoft) before building app

in this case you don't need to install it on agent.

otherwise you have to install library on each agent, or make dedicated agent.

Comment: Sorry , Have you deal with this process? Because Atalasoft has a wizard to register an create the .lic file which creates a user-machine association.